# Reg: phpunit says 'Warning No tests found in class "MyGuestbookTest".'

Tags: phpunit

first time in phpunit, With some reference tutorial, i created below code. i don't know what actually below code going to do.

```
<?php
class MyGuestbookTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @return PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_IDatabaseConnection
     */
    protected function getConnection()
    {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test","root", "");
        return $this->createDefaultDBConnection($db, "test");
    }

    /**
     * @return PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_IDataSet
     */
    public function getDataSet()
    {
      return $this->createXMLDataSet("seed.xml");
    }
}
?>
```

But i notices when the run the " phpunit MyGuestbookTest " in the command line. i am getting following error " No tests found in class "MyGuestbookTest"."

> D:\html\wamp\www\tdd>phpunit MyGuestbookTest PHPUnit 4.8.18 by
>   Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> F
>
> Time: 721 ms, Memory: 9.25Mb
>
> There was 1 failure:
>
> 1) Warning No tests found in class "MyGuestbookTest".
>
> FAILURES! Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Failures: 1.

please advice me to fix this error, also i would like to know, How this program call the methods after we ran the command in the command line.

how really working ?

Answer (score 0):

From phpunit documentation:

> The tests are public methods that are named test*.

Your test class don't have that kind of method, and that's why there is a "no tests" warning.